# Importing modules from different directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, packaging, setup.py

What is the pythonic way for absolute importing modules located in different directories in Python 3? I am able to import modules by modifying the `sys.path` but that method is hackey.

The alternative method, from what I've read, is to turn the project into a pip installable package. This is method beyond me, can someone elaborate on this process and logic? After writing a `setup.py` script, do I just `python setup.py install`, then all my modules and packages are in the right path and will work?

Answer (score 2):

### Loading a script dynamically from anywhere via a given path

```
import importlib.machinery
import imp
import os.path

path = '/home/user/testscript' # without .py
fname = os.path.basename(path)

namespace = fname.replace(' ', '_').strip('\\/;,. ') 

loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(namespace, os.path.abspath(path+'.py'))
handle = loader.load_module(namespace)
imp.reload(handle)

ret = handle.mainFunction()
```

`handle` being your library name. I just call it handle because I use it in a one shot test library myself so it gets deleted anyway in every iteration of the loop.

Sorry for syntax issues, wrote it on the phone. I'll correct any syntax issues or indentation issues in a few min.

### Minimalistic example would be:

```
import importlib.machinery

# Register the "mylib" namespace as "test.py"
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("mylib", r'C:\Users\OpenWindows\Desktop\test.py')
# And load that namespace
mylib = loader.load_module("mylib")

# And now we can call it whenever we want.
ret = mylib.someFunction()
```

### Traditional approach (not absolute path friendly)

Would be to just create a folder structure that looks like this:

```
|- main.py
|-- mylib /
|--        __init__.py
|--        mylib.py
```

And in the `__init__.py` file create something that looks like:

```
from mylib.mylib import *
```

That way, any function or class in `mylib.py` would be imported as if it resided in `main.py`. However, again this is heavily dependant on the subfolder residing in the same folder as the script you're executing. But it's also a traditional way of shipping/adding functionality to a application.

There's some other stuff you can do in the [`__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) file that might be useful. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Nice one, +1! But are there syntax issues?

Comment: @linusg - not sure, can't run it on my phone to test : /

Comment: thanks. I'll try it when I get to a computer. Is this the best way to import modules from different directories? It seems a little complex.

Comment: @MichaelB I'm sure there's better alternatives. For instance placing the libraries (modules) in a subdirectory and creating a `__init__.py` file. But that won't give you absolute import paths.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for a long time, and found the best method to create the `setup.py` file as you mentioned - don't worry, it's very easy. The basic one looks like this ([taken from python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example)):

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
  version='1.0',
  py_modules=['foo'],
  )
```

And then install it with pip using `-e` option:

```
 pip install -e <path-to-your-project>
```

This way you tell python to look for the module in your projects directory.